# LASTools file - conversion - laszip produces no output

Tags: las

I'm trying to convert a LAZ to LAS and am using LASTools laszip tool to get it done, but it won't produce an output. Here's what I get:

[image: Run Code]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try standalone LASTools? Or maybe use LAS2LAS? Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? Every program I can think of accepts LAZ as easily as LAS.

Comment: @Pointdump Neither Arc Desktop (https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000018224) nor Arc Pro (https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000018920) can open LAZ files.

Answer (score 1):

I just now used both LASZip and LAS2LAS in standalone LASTools to unzip your FL_PolkCo_2005-2007_000129.laz(20.1MB) to FL_PolkCo_2005-2007_000129.las(89.3MB).[image]

Comment: That's cool. I have two machines and am able to do it on one but no the other...

Comment: I'm migrating from Esri. ArcGIS Pro doesn't play with LAS. Sometimes their conversion tool fails. While on tech support, they suggested I go to QGIS and convert there. I haven't quite figured out how to replicate my entire workflow yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your path contains spaces. Therefore the command fails.
You could try to change the LAStools path to something like `C:\Lastools` or try to put the path in Quotation Marks (") in your QGIS Setup: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/basic_lidar.html